# fuel cms page information issue with Location fild

Tags: fuelcms

I am working with fuel cms 1.3.1 got an issue while creating page 
it have an mandatory field on Page Information section : "Location"

and i did not get the logic . do i have to create separate view file for each cms page i have to  created for their location [image]

and if i select an custom layout other than main layout it hides the cms section at admin panel .
what wrong i am doing or what step are missing  can one figure it out ??? help me out this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the fuel_mode property to 'auto' in fuel/application/config/MY_fuel.php:

```
$CI->fuel->config('fuel_mode') == 'auto';
```

[ref](http://forum.getfuelcms.com/discussion/2452/fuel-cms-page-information-issue-with-location-fild#Item_3)